# How to use skype SDK to join meetings with URI provided by the user

Tags: skypedeveloper

I have some queries regarding the functionality provided by the Skype SDK

1) Is it possible for my application to join a meeting url(provided to me by a user) as an attendee(bot)?

2) Is there a way to get all participants for that particular call?

3) Does skype sdk send events when a new participant joins the call?

4) Does the skype SDK send audio change events during a meeting?

5) What sdk should be used for the above use cases? I see Skype web SDK, UCMA and Trusted web application API. What are the differences between these and what should be suitable for the above use cases?

Comment: Have you tried going through Skype SDK documentation?

Comment: @Saheb I have gone through the documentation but the answers to these questions are still not clear. Moreover the documentation mentions many things for the same operations but it is not clear as to which one to use?